# Ember get request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ember.js

I am making an app using MongoDB, Ember, Express and Node.

My grade model is defined as follows:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    mark: DS.attr(),
    section: DS.attr(),
    student: DS.belongsTo('student', { async: true }),
    coursecode: DS.belongsTo('coursecode', { async: true }),
    programrecord: DS.belongsTo('programrecord', { async: true })
});
```

And my student model is defined as follows:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  number: DS.attr(),
  firstName: DS.attr(),
  lastName: DS.attr(),
  DOB: DS.attr(),
  resInfo: DS.belongsTo('residency',{ async: true }),
  gender: DS.belongsTo('gender',{ async: true }),
  country: DS.belongsTo('country',{ async: true }),
  province: DS.belongsTo('province',{ async: true }),
  city: DS.belongsTo('city',{ async: true }),
  grades: DS.hasMany('grade', { async: true }),
});
```

I am making a get request to query for all grades that have a specific mark:

```
GET to /grades?mark=100
```

I am also making a get request to query for grades that belong to a specific student (not sure if I am doing this correctly, I am passing in the ID of the student object):

```
GET to /grades?student=56d33a7896c31b6b1e40446a
```

How do I define the **route in the server.js** file to respond to this so I can return ONLY the grade objects with a mark of 100 or alternatively, return only the grade object that belongs to a student?

Comment: You can check the request parameter to determine what param is sent by the client and then return based on that

Answer (score 0):

This is the route used to respond to specific requests (ie. get grade objects that have a mark of xxx or get grade objects that belong to a student of id yyy) instead of returning ALL the grades:

```
app.route('/grades')
.post(function (request, response) {
    var grade = new GradeModel(request.body.grade);
    grade.save(function (error) {
        if (error) response.send(error);
        response.json({grade: grade});
    });
})
.get(function (request, response) {
    var Grade = request.query.grade;
    var mark = request.query.mark;
    var student = request.query.student;
    console.log(Grade);
    console.log(mark);
    console.log(student);

    if (student) {
        GradeModel.find({"student": student}, function (error, grades) {
            if (error) response.send(error);
            response.json({grade: grades});
        });
    }
    else if (mark) {
        GradeModel.find({"mark": mark}, function (error, grades) {
            if (error) response.send(error);
            response.json({grade: grades});
        });
    }
    else {
        GradeModel.find(function (error, grades) {
            if (error) response.send(error);
            response.json({grade: grades});
        });
    }
});
```

This is the query within an action inside a component:

```
   import Ember from 'ember';

   export default Ember.Component.extend({
        isGradesFormEditing: false,
        store: Ember.inject.service(),
        gradeModel: null,
        grades: null,
        ID: null,
        actions: {
            viewGrades () {
            var self = this;
            var myStore = this.get('store');
            myStore.query('grade', {student: this.get('ID')}).then(function (grades) {
                    console.log(grades);
                    self.set('grades', grades);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```